# AWS Lambda and DynamoDB stream. What if execution fail? Will the next attempt process the same record?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, aws-lambda

I'm creating a Lambda function (JavaScript) that gets exactly one record from several possible DynamoDB stream sources. The function includes a DynamoDB insert on another table, as audit-trail / notification system.

Let's say one execution fail due to throttling (too many inserts per second). 
As I'm calling context.fail() when the db.putItem fails, I expect that this record will be retried later on another execution. But I'm worried about the ordering.

My question is: Can I be sure that the next lambda execution (executed on the same instance or another) will get THIS errored record to process? And that the next record for the same source will NOT be processed until this one is successfully processed? (I have only this 'reader' for the source streams).

If not, how can I achieve this?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Dynamo streams are organized into shards, ordering within any single shard is preserved, and records will be retried before continuing.  When multiple shards are present however they are processed in parallel.

Dynamodb streams handle sharding automatically so you cannot guarantee order.  In practice when your TPS is low you should only be using 1 shard so order will be preserved.  I wouldn't rely on it though